# What programming language should I use to run physics simulations of CO2 being absorbed by different materials?

Tags: programming-languages, python

I want to model the absorption of CO2 with multiple different materials such as cement, limestone, wood, etc? I know Matlab is capable of these types of physics simulation according to this research paper: [Research Paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S025527011630006X), however, I am not sure if Python or another programming language could complete this task easier.

Comment: I'm not sure whether requests for programming language recommendations will be on-topic here.  Often, there is a significant advantage to choosing a language you are already familiar with.

Comment: You could try [Software recommendation](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1):

That depends on a lot of factors, mostly on available software for the task (you *don't* want to do the whole job yourself, if it is already done, or there are pieces you can combine with little effort, use that), in second line on how detailed your model (and it's computing requirements) is might force the use of inconvenient but efficient languages/packages.

This is probably a question better asked elsewhere, perhaps on a physics or chemistry forum (for the modelling aspects, and possibly for software alternatives in common use), or (given much more detailed requirements and specifications) on a forum on programming.

Answer (score 1):

I used to work on software that did something very similar, on geological scales (think carbon sequestration). My advice is very similar to that of vonbrand.

As others have noted, we don't really do programming language recommendations here. This group also isn't the main source of experts on this kind of programming; that would be [scicomp.SE](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/).

But don't just post your question as-is there, either. Do your homework first.

You want to consider how you are going to model the materials (1D, 2D, or 3D? regular grid? simplicial complex?) and the equations that you are going to solve (presumably involving some elliptic or parabolic PDEs) first. Then consider what sorts of techniques might solve those equations. Then look at what libraries are available.

For example, [algebraic multigrid](https://www.wias-berlin.de/people/john/LEHRE/MULTIGRID/multigrid_7.pdf) methods are very popular for diffusion-type equations that arise from physical systems, but you definitely wouldn't want to write one by yourself. There are some good ones available (MATLAB probably has one, and I think LLNL open sourced theirs). Also look around on sources like [GAMS](https://gams.nist.gov/) and see what's available.